# pygame ' video system not initialized' error using the cursors

Tags: cursor, pygame

i am trying to make some custom cursors for the programm i am making but i am getting a weird error; this is the cursor code i use:

```
arrows = ("XX                      ",
         "XXX                     ",
         "XXXX                    ",
         "XX.XX                   ",
         "XX..XX                  ",
         "XX...XX                 ",
         "XX....XX                ",
         "XX.....XX               ",
         "XX......XX              ",
         "XX.......XX             ",
         "XX........XX            ",
         "XX........XXX           ",
         "XX......XXXXX           ",
         "XX.XXX..XX              ",
         "XXXX XX..XX             ",
         "XX   XX..XX             ",
         "     XX..XX             ",
         "      XX..XX            ",
         "      XX..XX            ",
         "       XXXX             ",
         "       XX               ",
         "                        ",
         "                        ",
         "                        ")

datatuple, masktuple = pygame.cursors.compile(arrows,black='.', white='X',)
pygame.mouse.set_cursor( (24,24), (0,0), datatuple, masktuple)
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\eclipse\programms\src\editor.py", line 30, in <module>
pygame.mouse.set_cursor( (24,24), (24,24), datatuple, masktuple)
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

so i hope somebody know what the problem here is and if you might think it is my windows, i use windows 7 anyways(i have no idea what is wrong so i thought it might be the version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that error if you haven't called

```
pygame.init()
```

first.